# '80s cartoon movie or short that features a group of kids helping a professor or scientist with an electric experiment in his house

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm trying to find an '80s or early '90s cartoon that features a group of kids helping a professor or scientist with an electric experiment in his house. The overall colors are dark, like there's a storm coming, and the professor/scientist's house is several stories and looks almost like a haunted house.

I think the experiment is possibly to time travel, but I don't remember any actual time traveling happen. It might have Christian undertones but I'm not certain. The room the experiment is in is huge, lots of chrome and maybe light blue tiled floors.

Any and all suggestions welcomed! It's been driving me crazy for years and every time I try deep-dive googling I haven't found anything like it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_(TV_series)  Back to the future cartoon run in 1991-1992.